# Can someone help me decipher this groovy regex?

Tags: regex, groovy

```
static final Pattern EXAMPLE_PATTERN = ~/[A-Z0-9\[][A-Z0-9&\/][A-Z0-9]{1,4}/
```

This is a regex I was given and I am struggling to understand what exactly it limits. Thanks!

Comment: Check the regex on  [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/QHSudh/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `[A-Z0-9\[]` means a character that is an uppercase letter, a number, or `[`
- `[A-Z0-9&\/]` means a character that is an uppercase letter, a number, `&` or `/`
- `[A-Z0-9]{1,4}` means one to four characters that is are an uppercase letter, or a number

So `AA0000` will match.  As will `A[9` and `F/1234`

But `aaa` wont.  Nor will `AA`

Answer (score 0):

```
 [A-Z0-9\[]           # Single character,  of class A-Z or 0-9 or [
 [A-Z0-9&/]           # Single character,  of class A-Z or 0-9 or & or /
 [A-Z0-9]{1,4}        # 1 to 4 characters, of class A-Z or 0-9
```